# Shell-script to decrypt file

Tags: shell, sh, aes, rsa

I have to create a shell-script that can decrypt a RSA key file  that is encrypted with a specific .pem file. And then to decrypt zip file with the AES key which I get from the RSA file once it is decrypted in a file named keyaes (or whatever you want).
Here are the two commands I have to use

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -in AES_KEY -inkey CERTIFICATE.pem -out keyaes
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in zipfile.zip -out extraction.zip -nosalt -p -K RSA_KEY_from_key_aes_output -iv 0
```

The commands work perfectly, the problem is in my script I don't know how to make it automatically and to get the key from the keyaes output and put it into the next command properly.
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just use bash command substitution in the second command, using backticks

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in zipfile.zip -out extraction.zip -nosalt -p -K `cat output_filename_with_aes_key` -iv 0
```

Comment: `$(...)` is strongly preferred over backticks for all new scripts. And quote your expansions so they don't get split on whitespace into multiple arguments.

Comment: ...for bash specifically, you can also use `"$(<output_filename_with_aes_key)"` to avoid needing `cat` altogether; whereas `"$(cat output_filename_with_aes_key)"` will work on all shells compliant with the POSIX sh standard. Either way, `$(...)` is preferred to backticks, and the quotes are needed to prevent misbehavior caused by the key being subject to unintended word splitting or globbing.